# NuGet: explicitly list package dependencies as package references in project so they can be uninstalled

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

I'm creating a NuGet package (let's call it `Lib`) that also has analyzers in a separate package (`Lib.Analyzers`).

By default I want `Lib.Analyzers` to be installed to the the project when `Lib` is installed. I can achieve this by listing `Lib.Analyzers` in the dependencies of `Lib` (in the `.nuspec` file).

But I also want users to be able to *uninstall* `Lib.Analyzers` again when they don't want them.

AFAIK package dependencies are not listed as individual packages in the package manager and the following wouldn't work in the package manager console:

```
PM> Install-Package Lib
...
PM> Uninstall-Package Lib.Analyzers
Uninstall-Package : Package 'Lib.Analyzers' to be uninstalled could not be found in project 'ClassLibrary1'
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I couldn't find anything in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element).

## Rationale

I want to minimize friction for new users, i.e. they should get the help `Lib.Analyzers` provides without having to remember to install the analyzers every time they install `Lib`.

But I also want `Lib.Analyzers` to not be forced onto experienced users that might not want them anymore.

## Workaround

My current workaround would be to rename `Lib` to `Lib.Core`, remove its dependency to `Lib.Analyzers` and create a third meta-package named `Lib` that bundles the two, arriving at the following dependency graph:

```
Lib
|- Lib.Core
'- Lib.Analyzers
```

New users would then always install `Lib` and experienced ones could install only `Lib.Core` instead.

However, `Lib` is actually a rather small library so this solution feels a little "over-engineered".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a GitHub Issue about optional dependencies [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/686), which is closed.

So unfortunately it is not supported currently, and does not seems to be in the future.

[rohit21agrawal](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/686#issuecomment-362701732) gave the following close reason:

> Couple of reasons - we are closing bugs that have not been active for
> over a year, and two, this doesn’t fit in with the plans we have for
> NuGet in the near future.
>
> You can open a new issue if you have a **strong case** for this feature
> and we would consider it.

Maybe your issue is a *"strong case"*.

That being said, your workaround seems pretty good. More a documentation/introduction problem.

---

There is also an [option to suppress specific analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019#configure-severity-levels), if that is the root of your question.

[image: light bulb menu]

Comment: Ah well too bad. Thanks for finding the related issue.